# Checking a Proof of Apostol's Analysis Exercise 2.20

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and let there be an $M > 0$ such that
$$|f(x_{1}) + \cdots + f(x_{n})| \leq M$$
for $n \geq 1$ and for $x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n} \in [0, 1].$
We are to prove that,
if
$$S := \{ 0 \leq x \leq 1 \big| f(x) \neq 0 \},$$
then $S$ is countable.

We argue by contradiction.
Since
$|f(x)| \leq M$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, let 
$$A_{n} := \{0 \leq x \leq 1 \big| \frac{1}{n} < f(x) \leq M \},$$
$$B_{n} := \{0 \leq x \leq 1 \big| -M \leq f(x) < \frac{-1}{n} \}$$
for $n \geq 1.$ Then
$$S = \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}A_{n} \cup \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}B_{n}.$$
If $S$ is uncountable, then there is an $n \geq 1$ such that $A_{n}$ or $B_{n}$ is uncountable. W.l.o.g. let $A_{n}$ be uncountable. Then we can take $x_{1}, \dots, x_{k} \in A_{n}$ where $k > nM.$ Since
$f(x_{j}) > 1/n$ for $1 \leq j \leq k,$ we have
$$\sum_{1}^{k}f(x_{j}) > \frac{k}{n} > M,$$
$\rightarrow \leftarrow$.

However, I realized that the fact that we can take that many $x_{j} \in A_{n}$ can also be delivered if $A_{n}$ is countable, and if so then the contradiction is unraveled. Is it right or wrong?

Comment: Because the system seems to view the tag "natural numbers" as "elementary number theory", the latter is shown to us.

Comment: Sorry, the problem requires to prove for countability. I erroneously typed as uncountability. Now this is fixed.

Comment: Yes, you have also shown that each $A_n$ must be finite, but there is no problem with that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. Somehow I overlooked that being finite is being countable, ha :)